# How to link jar libraries while converting a jar file to dll using IKVM?

Tags: jar, ikvm

I have a Java application (JAR) that reads data from an Oracle database. I want to convert the JAR file to a .NET dll using IKVM. Can anyone suggest how to attach or link the ojdbc.jar to the jar file while creating the dll so that when I add the dll in a .NET project it should be able to read from the database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to simply include both jars when compiling with ikvmc:

ikvmc yourapp.jar ojdbc.jar -out:YourAppLibrary.dll

If this doesn't work at runtime, you need to look into IKVM class loading. See http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=ClassLoader for more information.